# Is there a way to configure Autofac to create inheritors of some base class to be single instances?

Tags: autofac

I am using Prism with Autofac, and I found myself couple of times having a bugs due to multiple instances of the ViewModel class which I expected to be single instance.

Thus my question is: how can I configure Autofac so that all inheritors from some base class (e.g. ViewModelBase) will always be single instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's very easy to do with container builder extension methods. This is one way

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
    .AssignableTo<ViewModelBase>()
    .SingleInstance();
```